# Can I edit files on a sub-domain with a PHP script in the parent domain?

Tags: php, hosting

I want to delete a folder dynamically in my subdomain with the help of a script that is in my main domain. Is that possible?

I am on shared hosting and using cPanel.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code, and where does it fail? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just forget the domains and use directories, just like you would on your computer. You need to know the directory of the file you want to edit, you can find it out with a simple :

```
<?php
echo __DIR__;
```